# Fastest way to compute Arctan2 on an FPGA

Tags: phase

Rip Van Winkle here -- is the fastest and least-footprint way to compute an arctan on an FPGA still to use CORDIC?

Or is there a way to leverage block RAM and DSP blocks to speed and/or reduce the size of the process?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/28814/4298)?

Comment: I hadn't -- my GoogleFu is abysmal, so even though I tried searching for it I still failed.

Comment: [This](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6928950/) is an interesting article. It suggests a rational approximation combined with a LUT. But more interestingly, it compares several approaches from the literature.

Comment: Wow that article is really great @MattL. I am almost thinking it's worthy as putting as a (short) answer somehow rather than being buried in the comments- understood it is just a link but very salient and full of good info for future reference.

Comment: Florent de Dinechin and Matei Istoan, "Hardware implementations of fixed-point Atan2", In *22nd IEEE Symposium on Computer Arithmetic*, June 2015, pp. 34-41: "This work essentially focuses on FPGAs. An unexpected result is that, even on modern FPGAs enhanced with DSP blocks and memories, CORDIC is a clear winner."

Comment: @njuffa I haven’t read the article yet (and looks good) but I wouldn't expect there to be any contest in favor of the CORDIC if speed is the primary concern.

Answer (score 16):

If you're willing to tolerate a possible absolute error of 0.26 degrees, you could use the following (from Chapter 13 of my "Understanding Digital Signal Processing" book):

[image]

The product 0.28125$Q^2$ is equal to (1/4+1/32)$Q^2$, so you can implement the product by adding $Q^2$ shifted right by two bits to $Q^2$ shifted right by five bits.

Here is the error curve, over the range of -45 degrees to +45 degrees

[image]

Comment: The division will be quite slow on an FPGA.

Comment: Unless you use CORDIC I don't think there's a way to avoid a divide with an atan2.

Comment: @TimWescott You can use a Maclaurin series to approximate the division.  But I have (in another answer) an approximation which avoids the problem.

Comment: @Graham: In terms of $x$ your method doesn't need a division, but with a power series approximation you'll always have a division if you're only given $I$ and $Q$ values. I think that is what Tim refers to.

Answer (score 12):

For some work fairly recently, I had a need for fast and accurate trig approximations which were at least C1 and ideally C2 continuous, because discontinuities in the first and second differentials were undesirable for our application.  I fitted polynomials to achieve this, working off a basic idea by [OlliW](http://www.olliw.eu/2014/fast-functions/).

For arctan, as with @RichardLyons' answer, I calculated this for octants 1 and 8 (to avoid having to fit a curve that tends to infinity).  The standard trig theorems then apply for using this in other octants. I normalised the output of the calculation to +/-1 = +/-45deg, so that scaling for degrees or radians simply requires an extra scaling.  Then available fits are

- $y = 0.157153894 x - 0.041596524 x^3 + 0.00944263 x^5$
- $y = 0.159154943 x - 0.051601768 x^3 + 0.023449972 x^5 - 0.006003146 x^7$
- $y = 0.159154943 x - 0.052424634 x^3 + 0.027564301 x^5 - 0.011763207 x^7 + 0.002468598 x^9$

For $y$ normalised to +/-1, worst-case errors are (respectively) 3.45e-4, 5.96e-5 or1.10e-6.  In degrees (multiply $y$ by 45 for error in degrees, or by $\pi/4$ for error in radians), that's a worst-case error of 0.016 degrees for the 5th-order fit.

This can be calculated effectively with an FPGA, using (respectively) 4, 5 or 6 cycles around an "$(A*B)+C$" DSP slice, or with a DSP.

Note that the nature of the equations as odd functions gives us the following for free:-

- ${\tt atan}(-x) = -{\tt atan}(x)$
- ${\tt atan}(0) = 0$
- $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}({\tt atan}(0)) = 0$

For anyone wanting to derive this themselves, this comes from solving simultaneous equations where:-

- For 5th order, ${\tt atan}$ values are correct at 30 degrees and 45 degrees, and the 1st differential is correct at 45 degrees.  This makes the fit C1 continuous when mapping to other octants.
- 7th order adds that the 1st differential is correct at zero.
- 9th order adds that the 2nd differential is correct at 45 degrees.  This makes the fit C2 continuous when mapping to other octants.

Answer (score 11):

To add to Richard's good answer please see this other [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66621/fast-phase-calculation/66644#66644) for additional estimators.

There really isn't much resource requirements for a CORDIC in an FPGA: Just an I, Q and phase accumulator and a very small look-up-table and notably no multipliers. It's an iterative algorithm with an approximate precision of $2^{-N-3}$ radians for $N$ iterations, and the look-up-table size need is just the ATAN2 results for only $N$ angles corresponding to each iteration ($\pi/4^n, n=1\ldots N$).  If the additional time for iteration is available, it would be a viable candidate for implementation if resources and/or power were a premium in dedicated hw solutions (hence it's prevalence in current use for Bluetooth receivers), especially if there are no dedicated multipliers available.

A high level summary of the algorithm is shown below where for an ATAN2 result we would operate the CORDIC in "Vectoring Mode" where we would use the CORDIC to rotate an unknown vector until the resulting angle of the rotated vector is 0 degrees as given by Q=0 and that way get both angle from the phase accumulator and magnitude from I.  The CORDIC as depicted below has a range of +/-90°. Extending this to +/-180° is done  by a +/-j rotation (which means simply swap I and Q and change the sign).

The CORDIC is the algorithm of choice when successive iteration time is available and there are no multipliers. If a complex multiplier is available then consider simply using a small Look-up table for the ATAN2 results of the $N$ binary weighted iterations down to any desired phase precision over $\pm \pi$ as $\pi/2^N$, and as done with "Vectoring Mode" in a CORDIC iterate over $N$ steps going in the direction based on the sign of $Q$ driving it to zero while accumulating the phase. This would have higher precision in less steps due to true binary weighted rotations (unlike the CORDIC) and not have the 1.647 CORDIC gain (if that was even an issue).

[image: CORDIC]

Also for consideration as an alternate to the CORDIC for hardware implementations is the [BKM algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BKM_algorithm).

Comment: "and notably no multipliers" -- yes.  But it's notable that just about any FPGA these days is sprinkled liberally with "DSP blocks" that implement "$(A \cdot B) + C$" in a hard-coded block.

Comment: @TimWescott right- I wouldn’t see any good reason to implement a CORDIC in an FPGA fabric but may be attractive for a low end microcontroller or hard ASIC implementation for extremely low cost low power receivers (where you see their use today). In an FPGA I would consider the multiplier based option I described.

Answer (score 3):

I designed two explicit approximations a while ago with the purpose of having a lowcost ArcTan2 to be done in FPGA fabric. In the end, I used different algorithms that needed no ArcTan2 at all, so I didn't use it in the end, and can't comment on performance. For the same reason, some details of the algorithm may evade me now.

[image]

*Fig. 1: The usual ArcTan2 function produces a smooth output. Only one branch shown.*

The axes are the two operands, with 0 being in the center of the image. The color codes the output range from -pi/2 to +pi/2.

My goal was to make an explicit approximate algorithm, that:

- needs no multiplications, but only shifts and adds
- is not iterative, but can run in a single clock cycle

The below simulations of the algorithm and code are from *Mathematica*. Let me know, if you have trouble understanding it. It uses regular floating point math, so I use things like `2^x` and `Log2@x` instead of shifts, and I manually `Round` numbers to force the discretization of integer arithmetic.

---

[image]

*Fig. 2: The approximation first takes the sign and absolute value of each operand and then goes through a series of `Ifs` and puts the decision together in the end*

```
Atan[x_, y_] := 
 Module[{xs = Sign[x], ys = Sign[y], xa = Abs[x], ya = Abs[y]},
  expx = Round@Log2@xa; (* number of leading 0s/1s *)
  expy = Round@Log2@ya; (* number of leading 0s/1s *)
  N@xs*ys*Which[
     expx == expy, \[Pi]/4,
     expx > expy, 2^(expy - expx),
     expx < expy, \[Pi]/2 - 2^(expx - expy)
     ] + If[xs == -1, ys*\[Pi], 0]
  ]
```

You can see, that the image turns blocky meaning that the result has steps and plateaus and is in general not exact. It is useful, however, if you only need to know the result approximately. I think I wanted to use this in a PLL, where feedback could take care of the nonlinearities.

---

[image]

*Fig. 3: This similar approximation has an output scaled to -0.5 .. +0.5. The code looks identical, but image slightly different. Not sure if it is different in terms of precision.*

```
Atan[x_, y_] := 
 Module[{xs = Sign[x], ys = Sign[y], xa = Abs[x], ya = Abs[y]},
  expx = Round@Log2@xa; (* number of leading 0s/1s *)
  expy = Round@Log2@ya; (* number of leading 0s/1s *)
  N@xs*ys*Which[
     expx == expy, 2^-3,
     expx > expy, 2^(expy - expx)/(2 \[Pi]),
     expx < expy, 2^-2 - 2^(expx - expy)/(2 \[Pi])
     ] + If[xs == -1, ys/2, 0]
  ]
```